# Strange behaviour when customdrawing a button

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created button controls on a dialog using winapi and I handle WM_NOTIFY -> NM_CUSTOMDRAW. 
The dialog is created by a menu command. The strange behavior is this: If I trigger the menu command by keyboard(pressing enter on menu item), Every thing is ok. If I mouse click the menu item to open the dialog box, Pressing the Alt key removes the text on button until I click or move mouse on a button. Tis happens once during the life of every dialog. How can I prevent this behavior? I draw the background of buttons and let windows draw text and bitmap on it. What is the problem with my code? Here is part of my code:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
static int uOnPrePaint(HWND hDlg, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpnmCD = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
    COLORREF crPen = GetDCPenColor(lpnmCD->hdc);
    bool bHot = (lpnmCD->uItemState & CDIS_HOT) != 0;
    COLORREF crBack = RGB(200, 200, 200);
    COLORREF crHot = RGB(200, 200, 0);
    SetDCBrushColor(lpnmCD->hdc, bHot ? crHot : crBack);
    SetDCPenColor(lpnmCD->hdc, bHot ? crHot : crBack);
    SelectObject(lpnmCD->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SelectObject(lpnmCD->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    int iThickness = 3;
    RoundRect(lpnmCD->hdc,
        lpnmCD->rc.left + iThickness,
        lpnmCD->rc.top + iThickness,
        lpnmCD->rc.right - iThickness,
        lpnmCD->rc.bottom - iThickness,
        5,
        5
    );
    SetDCPenColor(lpnmCD->hdc, crPen);
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hDlg, DWL_MSGRESULT, CDRF_DOERASE);
    return TRUE;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
static int uCustomDraw(HWND hwndDlg, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpnmCD = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
    switch (lpnmCD->dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT: return uOnPrePaint(hwndDlg, lParam);
    default: return (INT_PTR)0;
    }
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
static int uOnNotify(HWND hwndDlg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMHDR lpnmHeader = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
    switch (lpnmHeader->code)
    {
    case NM_CUSTOMDRAW: return uCustomDraw(hwndDlg, lParam);
    default: return (INT_PTR)0;
    }
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
static HWND uCreateButton(HWND hWnd, int cpx, int cpy, int cpWidth, int cpHeight, const wchar_t * wszText, int iIdControl)
{
    int style = BS_TEXT | BS_NOTIFY | BS_VCENTER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP;
    int styleEx = WS_EX_RTLREADING | WS_EX_RIGHT;
    HWND hwndControl = CreateWindowExW(
        styleEx, L"BUTTON", wszText, style,
        cpx, cpy, cpWidth, cpHeight,
        hWnd, nullptr, g_hInstance, nullptr
    );
    //ShowWindow(hwndControl, SW_SHOW);
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hwndControl, GWLP_ID, iIdControl);
    unsigned cpImageWidth = 16;
    HICON hIcon1 = (HICON)LoadImageW(g_hInstance, 
        MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_SMALL), IMAGE_ICON, cpImageWidth, cpImageWidth, LR_SHARED);
    if (hIcon1)
    SendMessageW(hwndControl, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hIcon1);
    return hwndControl;
}
```

Thanks in advance
mr.abzadeh
EDIT1: Question rewritten to better describe the problem and make it usable by others.
EDIT2: I noticed that this behavior is completely related to keyboard ease of access implemented in windows. I Opened Control Panel / Ease of Access Center / Make the Keyboard easier to use -> checked "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" check box and the problem is solved. But I want to solve the problem without modifying control panel settings. 
EDIT3: In another way I captured WM_KEYDOWN event of controls and posted a custom message to dialog, requiring to repaint all buttons on the dialog
when the ALT key is pressed for the first time, and this resolves my problem. But I leave the question open to see if there is a better way.

Comment: You should be restoring the original brush and pen after changing them. Might be related.

Comment: Saving and restoring gdi objects makes no difference, as I expected.

Comment: Restoring the DC is not going to fix your specific problem but you should still do it.

Answer (score 0):

Painting in response to `CDDS_PREPAINT` is probably problematic because you are asking windows to draw the background in certain scenarios with `CDRF_DOERASE`.

Try just returning `CDRF_DOERASE` in `CDDS_PREPAINT` and do the actual drawing in a later stage, perhaps in `CDDS_POSTERASE`.

Comment: drawing background in CDDS_POSTPAINT is worse because my code will clear text and bitmap; I changed CDRF_DOERASE to CDRF_NEWFONT

Comment: I thought you wanted to draw those yourself, if not, then delay to postpaint.  Keep in mind that RoundRect fills the rectangle unless the brush is hollow! If you want to draw the background and Windows to draw the text and icon then I'm not sure if that is possible (maybe try skipdefault in preerase stage) but you can just draw those yourself.

Comment: I noticed that this problem is completely related to keyboard ease of access. I  Opened Control Panel / Ease of Access Center / Make the Keyboard easier to use -> checked "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" and the problem is solved completely. Now the above code draws background and windows draws text and bitmap.